Type-checking custom class when creating or updating Firestore
This is the current way i'm creating and updating data in Firestore.

As you can see the "setData" object is not type checked which can result in typos and i wont notice if a change needs to be done when the "Report class" is updated.

class Report {
    var reporttitle:String
    var reportabout:String
    var reportlocation:String

    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        self.reporttitle = data["reporttitle"] as? String ?? ""
        self.reportabout = data["reportabout"] as? String ?? ""
        self.reportlocation = data["reportlocation"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}


var setData = [
     "reporttitle": "title",
     "reportabout": "about",
     "reportlocation": "location",
] as [String: Any]

 Firestore.firestore().collection("reports").addDocument(data: setData) { (err) in
     if let err = err { 
     } else {
        //Created...  
     }
}  

var setData = [
     "reporttitle": "title",
     "reportabout": "about",
] as [String: Any]

 Firestore.firestore().collection("reports").document( <reportid> ).updateData(setData) { (err) in
     if let err = err { 
     } else {
        //Updated...  
     }
}  

What would be a better way of doing this? That includes type-checking

(Creating) - all values from Report class
(Updating) - only selective values from Report class

